# How to sort JSON Array from API alphabetically?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift5

I'm a newbie in programming world, especially Swift. Now I am using Swift 5 in Xcode. By following code below, I successfully get JSON data from API and put it in Table View. This data default sorted by "id".
How to sort this data alphabetically based on "first_name" and put it in Table View?

```swift
// Model.swift
struct UserModel {
    var id: Int?
    var first_name: String?
    var last_name: String?

    init(data: JSON?) {
        self.id = data?["id"].int
        self.first_name = data?["first_name"].string
        self.last_name = data?["last_name"].string
    }
}

// UserViewController.swift
var users: [UserModel]?

// API Get result
switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                if let data = JSON(value).array {
                    self.users = data.map({ UserModel(data: $0) })
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

Comment: A simple [search on the task](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+sort+array+struct) will give you lots of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the `users` `array` using **`sort(by:)`** method like so,

```
users?.sort(by: { (user1, user2) -> Bool in
    if let name1 = user1.first_name, let name2 = user2.first_name {
        return name1 < name2
    }
    return false
})
```

**`sort(by:)`** sorts the collection in-place.

> Sorts the collection in place, using the given predicate as the
>   comparison between elements.

You can use **`sorted(by:)`** method for out-place sorting.

> Returns the elements of the sequence, sorted using the given predicate
>   as the comparison between elements.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 & Swift 4 & Swift 5**

```
self.users.sorted(by: { $0.first_name < $1.first_name})
```

Answer (score 1):

inorder to sort array struct in swift. you can simple do

```
self.users.sort(by: {$0.first_name < $1.first_name})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting for array of object can be done using below code

```
self.users.sorted(by: {$0.first_name < $1.first_name})
```

Sorting for ignore case.

```
self.users.sorted(by: {$0.first_name.lowercased() < $1.first_name.lowercased()})
```